# How i can covert string or object column itens to binary with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a column to a dataser in which there are 'negative' and 'positive' for binaries or numberable items like 0 and 1, but I don't know if I'm doing it right with the Pandas library.

```
pd.cut(data.Class, bins=['negative','positive'],labels=['0','1'])
```

but the following error appears:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'negative'
```

A dataset sample:

```
          v8      v9      Class  
0    0.00000  0.1224   negative  
1    0.00000  0.0000   negative  
2    0.00000  0.0000   negative  
3    0.00000  0.0000   negative  
4    0.00000  0.0561   negative  
..       ...     ...        ...  
166  0.66150  0.0000   negative  
167  1.06155  0.0000   negative  
168  1.62855  0.0000   negative  
169  1.71045  0.0000   positive  
170  1.54980  0.0000   positive
```

I would like the result to be as follows:

```
          v8      v9   Class  
0    0.00000  0.1224   0  
1    0.00000  0.0000   0  
2    0.00000  0.0000   0  
3    0.00000  0.0000   0  
4    0.00000  0.0561   0  
..       ...     ...    ...  
166  0.66150  0.0000   0  
167  1.06155  0.0000   0  
168  1.62855  0.0000   0  
169  1.71045  0.0000   1  
170  1.54980  0.0000   1
```

Comment: `pd.cut` arg `bins=` needs to be numeric.

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge so icant use it? what other function can I use?

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.cut()` arg `bins=` needs to be numeric, per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

> **bins : binsint, sequence of scalars, or IntervalIndex**

... so your approach wont work. try these instead:

```
# mapping
mapper = {'negative': 0, 'positive': 1}
df['Class'] = df['Class'].map(mapper)

# or numpy where
df['Class'] = numpy.where(df['Class'] == 'negative', 0, 1)

# or boolean mask
mask = df['Class'] == 'negative'

df.loc[mask, 'Class'] = 0
df.loc[~mask, 'Class'] = 1
```

all should give the same result:

```
        v8      v9 Class
0  0.00000  0.1224     0
1  0.00000  0.0000     0
2  0.00000  0.0000     0
3  0.00000  0.0000     0
4  0.00000  0.0561     0
5  0.66150  0.0000     0
6  1.06155  0.0000     0
7  1.62855  0.0000     0
8  1.71045  0.0000     1
9  1.54980  0.0000     1
```

Comment: almost, but if you test all the functions they transform all the elements into a single Boolean value. :/

Answer (score 0):

If the values are only 'negative' and 'positive', I'd probably build a new column using something like:

```
data['BinaryClass'] = data['Class'] == 'positive'
```

This will turn anything that is equal to the string "positive" to a True boolean value and anything not equal to "positive" to false. Then you can easily convert to integer types, etc... as needed.

Comment: thanks for the help, but with this all classes will be transformed into just one